# ERROR when adding 2 OR MORE .jar files. Duplicate class found in modules (Android). Is there a way to merge or exclude duplicate class?

Tags: java, android, wso2, dependencies, siddhi

I am doing an Android app and I am trying to use several extension adding them through jar files.
But when I compile and run, I have the following error:

```
Duplicate class com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.ExclusionStrategy found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.FieldAttributes found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy$1 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy$2 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy$3 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy$4 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy$5 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.FieldNamingStrategy found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.Gson found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.Gson$1 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.Gson$2 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.Gson$3 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.Gson$4 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.Gson$5 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.GsonBuilder found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.InstanceCreator found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.JsonArray found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.JsonElement found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.JsonIOException found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.JsonNull found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.JsonObject found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.JsonParseException found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.JsonParser found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.JsonSerializer found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.JsonStreamParser found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.LongSerializationPolicy found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.LongSerializationPolicy$1 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.LongSerializationPolicy$2 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.TypeAdapter found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.TypeAdapter$1 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.annotations.Expose found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.annotations.Since found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.annotations.Until found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Preconditions found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$GenericArrayTypeImpl found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$ParameterizedTypeImpl found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$WildcardTypeImpl found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$1 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$10 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$11 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$12 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$2 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$4 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$5 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$6 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$7 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$8 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$9 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.Excluder found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.Excluder$1 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.JsonReaderInternalAccess found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.LazilyParsedNumber found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap$1 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap$EntrySet found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap$EntrySet$1 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap$KeySet found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap$KeySet$1 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap$LinkedTreeMapIterator found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap$Node found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.ObjectConstructor found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.Primitives found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.Streams found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.Streams$AppendableWriter found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.Streams$AppendableWriter$CurrentWrite found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.UnsafeAllocator found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.UnsafeAllocator$1 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.UnsafeAllocator$2 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.UnsafeAllocator$3 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.UnsafeAllocator$4 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter$1 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter$1 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.bind.JsonTreeReader found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.bind.JsonTreeReader$1 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.bind.JsonTreeWriter found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.bind.JsonTreeWriter$1 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter$1 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter$2 found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory found in modules jetified-siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar (siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar) and jetified-siddhi-map-json-4.1.2.jar (org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

This is my build.gradle (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.champeau.gradle.antlr4'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "uca.es.geoprueba"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    configurations{
        all{
            exclude group: "org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json", module: "siddhi-map-json"
            resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        merge 'META-INF/annotations/org.wso2.siddhi.annotation.Extension'
        merge 'META-INF/annotations/io.siddhi.annotation.Extension'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'

    }
}

antlr4 {
    extraArgs = ['-package', 'org.wso2.siddhi.query.compiler']
    output = project.file("src/main/java/org/wso2/siddhi/query/compiler")
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation('org.wso2.siddhi:siddhi-core:4.5.11') {
        transitive = false
    }
    implementation('org.wso2.siddhi:siddhi-query-api:4.5.11') {
        transitive = false
    }
    implementation('org.wso2.siddhi:siddhi-query-compiler:4.5.11') {
        transitive = false
    }
    implementation('org.wso2.siddhi:siddhi-annotations:4.5.11') {
        transitive = false
    }
    annotationProcessor('org.wso2.siddhi:siddhi-annotations:4.5.11') {
        transitive = false
    }

    implementation ('org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:4.1.2'){
        transitive = false
    }

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:24.1-jre'
    implementation('org.apache.log4j.wso2:log4j:1.2.17.wso2v1') {
        transitive = false
    }
    implementation 'org.osgi:org.osgi.core:6.0.0'
    implementation 'org.wso2.orbit.com.lmax:disruptor:3.4.2.wso2v1'
    implementation 'org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.8'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.2'
    implementation 'io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:4.1.2'
    implementation files('libs/siddhi-gpl-execution-geo-4.0.18.jar')

}
```

I have already tried this solution: 
[Why I'm Getting Duplicate Class When Running My Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029393/why-im-getting-duplicate-class-when-running-my-android-project)

Although the same error does not appear, it gives an error when executing it. It is as if you only took one of the jar files into account. This is the error:

```
2020-03-13 11:52:33.879 12164-12164/uca.es.geoprueba E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: uca.es.geoprueba, PID: 12164
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{uca.es.geoprueba/uca.es.geoprueba.MainActivity}: org.wso2.siddhi.core.exception.SiddhiAppCreationException: Error on 'geofencingSiddhi' @ Line: 1. Position: 232, near '@source(type='inMemory', @map(type='json', enclosing.element='STRING', fail.on.missing.attribute='false')) define stream inStream(id string, latitud double, longitud double, geoJSONGeometryFence string)'. No extension exist for sourceMapper:json
```

Is there a way to merge duplicate classes or exclude some of them?

Comment: use `gradle -q dependencies --configuration implementation` to get dependency tree for configuration `implementation`. find duplicate libraries. add `exclude {...}` definition for duplicate libraries.

Comment: @daggett where do i have to add exclude {...}? can you put an example please?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:excluding-transitive-deps

Comment: @dagget i can't find any duplicate library. This is the result of my build gradle tree: `\--- org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo:siddhi-gpl-execution-geo:4.0.18 (n)
+--- org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json:siddhi-map-json:5.0.1 (n)

(n) - Not resolved (configuration is not meant to be resolved)`

Comment: so, there is no such artifact/version in public repositories. i don't see version 4.0.18 : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.geo/siddhi-gpl-execution-geo

Comment: if I use the last version in the public repositories (4.0.9) the same error occur

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to fix it.

I have followed this solution:

[Duplicates class found in modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58946207/duplicates-class-found-in-modules)