# Duplicate class found facebook sdk unity

Tags: c#, android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-sdk-4.0

Hi I am working with unity.

I am trying to build my application in android

I am getting this error when building. Normally I can play the game in unity. I am building for android.
I have a Keystore. I created a key.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class 
        com.facebook.android.BuildConfig found in modules
        jetified-facebook- android-
        wrapper-7.17.2-runtime.jar (:facebook-android-wrapper-7.17.2:)
        and jetified- facebook-android-wrapper-8.0.0-runtime.jar (:facebook- 
        android-wrapper-8.0.0:)
    
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

I looked at these links

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-for-unity/issues/386
[Duplicates class found in modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58946207/duplicates-class-found-in-modules)
https://forum.unity.com/threads/androidx-corecomponentfactory-problem-on-2019-3.777584/#post-5193863

But it does not solve my problem. I am getting still the same errors.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

It seems adding voodoo packes in unity and facebook is conflicting. If you have voodoo packages you do not need to add facebook sdks again.